# RethinkDB windows installation

Tags: node.js, database, rethinkdb, reql, nosql

Hi had downloaded rethinkdb and run exe file but it is not connected while 
in browser but it is showing following in console

```
    Running rethinkdb 2.3.5-windows (MSC 190023506)...
Running on 6.2.9200 (Windows 8, Server 2012)
Loading data from directory C:\rethinkdb_data
Listening for intracluster connections on port 29015
Listening for client driver connections on port 28015
Listening for administrative HTTP connections on port 8080
Listening on cluster address: 127.0.0.1
Listening on driver address: 127.0.0.1
Listening on http address: 127.0.0.1
To fully expose RethinkDB on the network, bind to all addresses by running rethinkdb with the `--bind all` command line option.
Server ready, "DESKTOP_KDCUFAP_wxu" 1612d866-4f12-4b73-b45a-777bf9b84740
```

Browser side

Connected to
<Unknown>
Issues
No issues
Servers
connected
Tables
/ ready
Servers

```
0 servers connected
0 servers missing
```

Tables

```
0 tables ready
0 tables with issues
```

Indexes

```
0 secondary indexes
0 indexes building
```

Resources

```
NaN% cache used
0 Bytes disk used
```

Comment: Browser side it is showing connected to <Unknown>

Comment: Does your browser's JavaScript console report any errors?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The RethinkDB 2.3.5 web UI does not work in the Edge browser. Are you able to load it in another browser?

> https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/5878

The next version of RethinkDB will have a fix for this bug.

Comment: No i am unable to load any of the browsers in my system. But it is working fine in my browser if i run RethinkDB from server